# Blank screen after relocating the expo entryPoint

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a react-native project and I'm using expo.

In my project structure I have the sources folder that contain all my sources expect the App.js file.

I would like to have this file in the sources folder as well.

For this I created a app.json file as follow:

```
{
    "expo": {
            "entryPoint": "./sources/App.js",
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I do so after running the app with:

> expo start --web

The server is launched the app is open in my browser but I have a blank screen.

There is no log, no error.

I can also add that the render method of the App.js isn't called because I put a console.log("Hello") that doesn't appear.

I don't undertstand the behaviour.

Isn't modifying the entryPoint property the way to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#custom--main--entry-point-in) state 'Support for custom entry points is in progress and is coming soon.' and suggest doing the following:

Create an `index.js`/`index.ts` file in your root folder with this content:

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import App from './src/App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

where `from './src/App'` represents the entry location. Also delete the line

`"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",`

from your `package.json` and any `entryPoint` keys in `app.json` or `app.config.js`/`app.config.ts`

This worked for me.